# Prepopulate Django Forms on Jquery Page Redirect

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, django-templates, django-views

I have a page that displays the history of some of the previous form submissions by a user. I have used the following code to extract this data from a table on the page:

```
$( "#rerun-conv-input" ).click(function() {
    // alert( "Handler for .click() called." );
    console.log($(".edf-run-detail.active.show").children());

    var json_input_list = new Array();

    $table = $(".edf-run-detail.active.show")

    $table.find('tr').each(function (i, el) {
        var $tds = $(this).find('td');
        var value = $tds.eq(1).text();
        json_input_list.push(value);

    }); 

    var json_input = {
        "input1" : json_input_list[0],
        "input2" : json_input_list[1],
        "input3" : json_input_list[2],
        "input4" : json_input_list[3],
        "input5" : json_input_list[4],
    }

    ...
    window.location.assign("{% url 'form-conversion' %}");
    ...
```

How do I include the previously submitted form inputs from `json_input_list` through my page redirect?

I believe I have to do it by passing it through the URL, but I am worried my inputs might be too large to fit the size of a URL. Any help is much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could theoretically store them in a cookie and then retrieve them on the next page. The easiest way would be to use js-cookie (https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie)

Example:

```
// set a cookie
Cookies.set(“name”, “value”)

// get a cookie
Cookies.get(“name”)

// delete a cookie
Cookies.remove(“name”)
```

Important note: I would have the cookies cleared/deleted via ‘.remove()’ after you use them on the next page. Also, you should not store any sensitive data in cookies *ever*.

Comment: I'm planning on using sessionStorage to the same effect. Would that work?